# Hanzi for xuetou

Tags: characters

[*La société chinoise depuis 1949*](https://www.collectionreperes.com/catalogue/index-La_soci__t___chinoise_depuis_1949-9782348040849.html) by Tania Angeloff (2018; in French) is a book about Chinese society since 1949. The author sometimes uses pinyin without tones to give the Chinese counterparts of some of the terms used in the book.

For example, on page 87 she uses the term *xuetou* (French: "patrons de sang"), i.e. people who collected blood from impoverished farmers (taking advantage of farmers who tried to make a bit of money through this type of scheme in the late 1980s; the xuetou didn't do any blood tests, which led to the spread of diseases through blood transfusion). However, the Hanzi for this term are not shown in the text. I assume "xue" is actually 血 (xuè), but I'm not entirely sure about "tou". Does this correspond to 头?

Based on [xuetou in MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=xuetou) I'm not really sure.

Comment: Looks like it is 血头 : https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%A1%80%E5%A4%B4

Comment: Why did this question get a downvote? The word could not be found in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

At first, as a native speaker, I have never seen that before.

As soon as I saw it in [here:血头](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%A1%80%E5%A4%B4), I will know it immediately, the structure of this word more like "捕头".

The meaning of "头"([head](http://www.zdic.net/z/17/js/5934.htm)) is easy to understand just like the meaning in english.

From the perspective of "组词"(combine words), I think it's rather a quick and short denote for "组织他人卖血者"

For example "公号", short for "公众号", can be used to save one char compare to "公众号", it's not a native word, but still in use.